Помочь нажать на элемент в selenium
Вот когда элемент не активен
<div class="css-gk32fl"><label data-testid="select-500" for="weight-500" class="css-1s82asb"><div class="css-1h0qipy"> 0-0.5 кг<input id="weight-500" name="weight" type="radio" class="css-17jnaqn" value="500"> </div></label></div>

Вот когда активен
<div class="css-gk32fl"><label data-testid="select-500" for="weight-500" class="css-hf9396"><div class="css-1h0qipy"> 0-0.5 кг<input id="weight-500" name="weight" type="radio" class="css-17jnaqn" value="500"> </div></label></div>

1s82asb меняется на hf9396
def data_button_weight_small(driver):
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    try:
        click_weight_small = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@id="weight-1000"]')))
        if click_weight_small.is_displayed():
            click_weight_small.click()
        else:
            print("Элемент 0.5-1 кг не отображается и не кликабелен")
    except ElementClickInterceptedException:
        print("Элемент 0.5-1 кг не кликабелен")

Вот код вставляю что угодно вместо input.id. Но всегда показывает что не кликабелен элемент. Есть идеи как бы можно было бы на него нажать

Добавьте, пожалуйста, данные для получения адекватного ответа. Ссылка на сайт, выдаваемая ошибка. Почему вы не используете element_to_be_clickable?
